# Why is formatting now removed from pasted test? And how do I fix it?

Tags: email, html

I've been using CiviCRM since June '15. I email my group 2-3 times per month, copy-and-pasting an online event listing. The text and image formatting used to be preserved but in the last 3? months it's been removed. I tried different browsers to no avail.

Now my events look lousy and I'm frustrated. I'm a volunteer and not in IT. Help with this would be wonderful!

10/19 Eta email original text:

```
Delivered-To: summer.gray@gmail.com
Received: by 10.64.5.165 with SMTP id t5csp516262iet;
        Wed, 19 Oct 2016 13:16:00 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.233.237.195 with SMTP id c186mr3464037qkg.29.1476908160522;
        Wed, 19 Oct 2016 13:16:00 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <summer@arthritisintrospective.org>
Received: from server269.com (server269.com. [64.14.68.35])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id t185si14877207qkd.182.2016.10.19.13.16.00
        for <summer.gray@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Wed, 19 Oct 2016 13:16:00 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: 64.14.68.35 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of summer@arthritisintrospective.org) client-ip=64.14.68.35;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=neutral (google.com: 64.14.68.35 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of summer@arthritisintrospective.org) smtp.mailfrom=summer@arthritisintrospective.org
Received: (qmail 7399 invoked by uid 5747); 19 Oct 2016 20:15:59 -0000
Message-ID: <20161019201559.7398.qmail@server269.com>
To: summer.gray@gmail.com
Subject: Test
X-PHP-Script: www.arthritisintrospective.org/index.php for 67.160.101.38
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="=_6206fb52d8bcdfde729dd2afaa1ba42c"
From: Summer Gray <summer@arthritisintrospective.org>
Cc: 
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Reply-To: Summer Gray <summer@arthritisintrospective.org>
Date: Wed, 19 Oct 2016 13:15:59 -0700

--=_6206fb52d8bcdfde729dd2afaa1ba42c
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8



--
Summer Gray
Arthritis Introspective
Arthritis Support Network Leader Seattle, WA
Summer@arthritisintrospective.org
C: (503) 550-4333

UNSUBSCRIBE: To unsubscribe, reply with “remove” as the subject. We respond to requests immediately.
--=_6206fb52d8bcdfde729dd2afaa1ba42c
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

<h1 id="page-title">AI Seattle - November Coffee and Chat</h1>

<p>It looks like you are already registered for this event. If you want to change your registration, or you feel that you&#39;ve gotten this message in error, please contact the site administrator. You can also&nbsp;<a href="https://www.arthritisintrospective.org/civicrm/event/register?reset=1&amp;id=455&amp;cid=0">register another participant</a>.</p>

<ul id="actions">
    <li>&nbsp;</li>
</ul>

<p>Let&#39;s grab a cup of coffee (or tea) and chat!</p>

<p><img alt="" src="https://www.arthritisintrospective.org/sites/default/files/civicrm/persist/contribute/images/AF-AI%20Lock%20up%20lg%20website.png" /></p>

<p><strong>Arthritis Support Network - Seattle</strong></p>

<p><strong>Please join us for a community support group for people with arthritis and rheumatic diseases.</strong></p>

<p>Our Arthritis Support Network provides help &amp; support to adults living with all types of arthritis and rheumatic diseases. Join our network for Connection, Education and Empowerment.</p>

<hr />
<p><img alt="Jewel Box Cafe logo" src="http://www.jewelboxcafe.net/images/jewel_logo.jpg" /></p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>Come join us at&nbsp;<a href="http://www.jewelboxcafe.net/">Jewel Box Cafe</a>&nbsp;for AI Seattle&#39;s November monthly meeting!&nbsp; We meet, talk about life, and relax with people who understand.</p>

<p>Please RSVP so we know who to expect.&nbsp;We understand that RSVPs can be difficult to keep, so no pressure and come if you&#39;re able.</p>

<p>Friends, family, spouses and significant others are welcome!&nbsp;</p>

<p>Hope to see you!</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p><label>When</label></p>

<p><abbr title="November 13th, 2016  3:00 PM">November 13th, 2016 3:00 PM</abbr>&nbsp;&nbsp; through &nbsp;&nbsp;<abbr title=" 5:00 PM">5:00 PM</abbr></p>

<p><label>Location</label></p>

<p>Jewel Box Cafe<br />
321 NE Thornton Pl<br />
Seattle,&nbsp;WA&nbsp;98125<br />
United States</p>

<p><canvas draggable="false" height="512" width="512"></canvas></p>

<p><img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/StaticMapService.GetMapImage?1m2&amp;1i2687655&amp;2i5852490&amp;2e1&amp;3u16&amp;4m2&amp;1u425&amp;2u350&amp;5m5&amp;1e0&amp;5sen-US&amp;6sus&amp;10b1&amp;12b1&amp;token=100628" /></p>

<p><img alt="" draggable="false" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i16!2i10499!3i22861!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i366039178!3m9!2sen-US!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e47!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0!5m1!5f2&amp;token=47607" /></p>

<p><img alt="" draggable="false" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i16!2i10499!3i22862!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i366039178!3m9!2sen-US!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e47!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0!5m1!5f2&amp;token=7886" /></p>

<p><img alt="" draggable="false" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i16!2i10498!3i22861!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i366039178!3m9!2sen-US!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e47!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0!5m1!5f2&amp;token=116716" /></p>

<p><img alt="" draggable="false" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i16!2i10498!3i22862!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i366039178!3m9!2sen-US!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e47!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0!5m1!5f2&amp;token=76995" /></p>

<p><img alt="" draggable="false" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i16!2i10500!3i22861!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i366039178!3m9!2sen-US!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e47!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0!5m1!5f2&amp;token=90733" /></p>

<p><img alt="" draggable="false" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i16!2i10500!3i22862!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i366039178!3m9!2sen-US!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e47!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0!5m1!5f2&amp;token=51012" /></p>

<p><a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=47.702475,-122.324611&amp;z=16&amp;t=m&amp;hl=en-US&amp;gl=US&amp;mapclient=apiv3" target="_blank" title="Click to see this area on Google Maps"><img draggable="false" src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/google4_hdpi.png" /></a></p>

<p>Map data &copy;2016 Google</p>

<p><a href="https://www.google.com/intl/en-US_US/help/terms_maps.html" target="_blank">Terms of Use</a></p>

<p><a href="https://www.google.com/maps/@47.7024746,-122.324611,16z/data=!10m1!1e1!12b1?source=apiv3&amp;rapsrc=apiv3" target="_new" title="Report errors in the road map or imagery to Google">Report a map error</a></p>

<p><img draggable="false" src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/tmapctrl_hdpi.png" /></p>

<p><img draggable="false" src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/tmapctrl_hdpi.png" /></p>

<p><img draggable="false" src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/cb_scout5_hdpi.png" /></p>

<p><img draggable="false" src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/cb_scout5_hdpi.png" /></p>

<p><img draggable="false" src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/cb_scout5_hdpi.png" /></p>

<p>Map</p>

<p>Satellite</p>

<p><br />
<a href="https://www.arthritisintrospective.org/civicrm/contact/map/event?eid=455&amp;reset=1" title="Show large map">Show large map</a></p>

<p><label>Contact</label></p>

<p>Phone:&nbsp;(206) 432-9341&nbsp;</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p><a href="https://www.arthritisintrospective.org/civicrm/event/ical?reset=1&amp;id=455" title="Download iCalendar entry for this event."><img alt="Download iCalendar entry for this event." src="https://www.arthritisintrospective.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/i/office-calendar.png" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="https://www.arthritisintrospective.org/civicrm/event/ical?reset=1&amp;list=1&amp;id=455" title="iCalendar feed for this event."><img alt="iCalendar feed for this event." src="https://www.arthritisintrospective.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/i/ical_feed.gif" /></a></p>

<h3>Help spread the word</h3>

<p>Please help us and let your friends, colleagues and followers know about our page:&nbsp;<a href="https://www.arthritisintrospective.org/civicrm/event/info?id=455&amp;reset=1">AI Seattle - November Coffee and Chat</a></p>

<p><iframe allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.html?text=AI%20Seattle%20-%20November%20Coffee%20and%20Chat&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.arthritisintrospective.org%2Fcivicrm%2Fevent%2Finfo%3Fid%3D455%26amp%3Breset%3D1"></iframe></p>

<p><iframe allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=240719639306341&amp;href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.arthritisintrospective.org%2Fcivicrm%2Fevent%2Finfo%3Fid%3D455%26amp%3Breset%3D1&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light"></iframe></p>

<p><br />
&nbsp;</p>

<p>You can also share the below link in an email or on your website.&nbsp;<br />
<a href="https://www.arthritisintrospective.org/civicrm/event/info?id=455&amp;reset=1">https://www.arthritisintrospective.org/civicrm/event/info?id=455&amp;reset=1</a></p>

<p><br />
--</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<div>Summer Gray<br />
<a href="https://www.arthritisintrospective.org">Arthritis Introspective</a><br />
Arthritis Support Network Leader Seattle, WA<br />
<span class="text_exposed_show"><a href="mailto:Summer@arthritisintrospective.org">Summer@arthritisintrospective.org</a><br />
C: (503) 550-4333<br />
<br />
UNSUBSCRIBE: To unsubscribe, reply with &ldquo;remove&rdquo; as the subject. We respond to requests immediately.</span></div>

--=_6206fb52d8bcdfde729dd2afaa1ba42c--
```

Comment: Summer, sorry to hear you're having problems! You can help others answer your question by adding more detail - eg where you were copying the event info from (maybe give URL of your event?), and how you were sending the info out (maybe CiviMail, maybe via Gmail, maybe another app). Detailed questions ⇒ informed answers :) Edit your question or add a comment if you can - I've upvoted this Q to help get you past the "new user" limits.

Comment: it'd also be good to know if your civicrm site has been upgraded recently.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I believe our Civi recently upgraded but can't find its release #. Is CiviMail just sending email w/in the site? That's where I'm having trouble. I've tried to self educate about civi but the tutorials were too advanced.

Comment: And I hit enter :p

Let's see if I can link correctly. I'm used to standard html.  
@Chris, One event [URL](http://www.arthritisintrospective.org/civicrm/event/info?reset=1&id=455). And the resulting [wonky email](https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8138/29694012313_d8d3317579_z.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK - the most obvious changes seem to be that some colours and fonts are removed.

You've said you're not a coder, so I understand if this feels "too hard" to debug yourself. I'll share with you what I'd do next, and hope this is some help.

In your situation I would compare:

- The source of the email as saved in the database. (You're looking for the `body_html` column in the table `civicrm_mail`.)
- The source of the email as received. (Varies per mail client; search the web for "how to view email source" + your mail app name.)
- The email as *displayed* in GMail. Some webmail services strip CSS from the rendered version online, so it's possible GMail just shows the email differently.

#### Edited below based on additional info

The green text in your event listing has this source (reformatted here).

```
<p style="text-align: center;">
  <span style="font-size:28px;">
    <span style="color: rgb(0, 128, 0);">
      <strong>
        <span style="font-family: Tahoma,Geneva,sans-serif;">
          Arthritis Support Network - Seattle
        </span>
      </strong>
    </span>
  </span>
</p>
```

In the email you've received, that has been reduced to:

```
<p><strong>Arthritis Support Network - Seattle</strong></p>
```

... which lacks

- several `<span>` tags, and
- all the inline style declarations

So it looks like the **formatting was stripped when pasting to CiviCRM's Rich Text Editor** (RTE).

If that's the case, the simple solution would be to bypass the RTE by setting both the event editor and civimail editor to "source" mode before copying and pasting between them.

(Another approach would be to reconfigure your RTE to be more permissive about pasted HTML.)

To verify this is the cause:

1. Identify the mailing that went out as shown in CiviCRM's list of "Scheduled and Sent" mails, make a note of the ID there.
2. Use PHPMyAdmin or MySQL CLI or some other means of inspecting your CivICRM database directly (ask your hosting provider for support on how)
3. Locate the table `civicrm_mailing`
4. Locate the row with corresponding ID from (1) above
5. View the column `body_html`
6. Locate the text "Arthritis Support Network - Seattle" in this value
7. See whether you see the surrounding `<span>` tag with inline CSS

If you do NOT see the `<span>` tag there, then the formatting was not saved  when editing the email in CiviCRM, which is probably the RTE "cleaning" it for you.

As above - copying and pasting in "source mode" is probably your best workaround for the RTE stripping formatting when copy pasting.

Sending a few test emails before scheduling the main mailout is recommended - when one has been editing the copy all day, it's easy to miss absolute clangers if someone "fresh" doesn't get to look at it. Fresh eyes can spot things like "but that's entirely the wrong logo!" :D

Comment: Thanks @Chris! I think this is way beyond my pay grade, unfortunately. I have autoimmune disease and it has screwed with my ability to think in some technical ways :/

Comment: @summer - providing more info may be easier than you. If you are able to view the email in gmail, then copying and pasting the 'Show Original' text would help us solve the mystery. (see [screenshot](https://s12.postimg.org/oys20glcd/gmail_menu.png))

Comment: @michaelmcandrew Ok, had to send the email to my gmail acct. Here it is:

Comment: @summer want to try that link again? EDIT: nvm found it in updated question :D

Comment: Answer updated, sorry it's so long!

Comment: Thank you so much @ChrisBurgess! Rich text vs html is my bane. As is return-to-send :p
I'll tackle this more when my brain's online. Your answer is very helpful and I have hope :)